# trouble with inner joining 2 tables

Tags: sql, database, join, inner-join

I have a database with 2 tables in it one is **'enlistments'** and the other one is **'users'**. In the enlistments table I have a user_id and in the users table I have a name. I want to get the name of the user which belongs to the id.

I know I need to do this with an inner join like this:

```
SELECT enlistments.round_id, users.name
FROM enlistments
INNER JOIN users
ON enlistments.user_id=users.name
WHERE enlistments.activity_id = 1;
```

However I get this error: Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

I did some research and found out it has to do with comparing an int with a string but I don't know how to solve the problem.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgfZB.png) is how my database looks like

Comment: you are joining int and string columns on clause. this is the case, you must change like in the answer

Answer (score 2):

`join on` is the condition you use to join the tables. Here it's `enlistments.user_id=users.id`.

```
select  e.round_id
       ,u.name
from    enlistments e join users u on u.id = e.user_id
where   activity_id = 1
```

| round_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Tuifa6a)

Comment: when doing this i dont get an error which is good. but im not getting any data

Comment: I got it working the way you showed it first in phpmyadmin. but when i use the exact same piece of code in my code editor i get the error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'enlistments.round_id' in 'field list'

Comment: The error "unknown column name" could not be more precise. Please think about what you are doing.

Comment: i know it has something to do with 'enlistments.round_id' but when I run the query in phpmyadmin it shows a result but when i add the exact same to my code it gives the error

Answer (score 0):

To validate and be sure you are pulling back the exact data desired, I usually provide aliases for each column brought back and make sure to bring back the join columns also. It's good practice to label where the columns returned originated.

```
SELECT 
Enlistments.UserID as Enlistments_UserID,
Users.ID as Users_ID,
enlistments.round_id as Enlistments_RoundID, 
users.name as Users_Name
FROM enlistments
INNER JOIN users
ON enlistments.user_id=users.id
WHERE enlistments.activity_id = 1;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT EN.round_id, US.name
FROM enlistments EN
INNER JOIN users US 
        ON US.name= CAST(EN.user_id AS VARCHAR) 
WHERE EN.activity_id = 1
```

What you are needing is the function cast that can convert any kind of data into another, so you'll pass your integer value as the first argument followed by `"AS '%DATATYPE'"` where `%DATATYPE` is the kind of data you want to achieve.

In your case:

```
SELECT CAST(123456 AS VARCHAR)
-- RETURNS : '123456'
```

Anyway, I’m not sure that you can be able to join these two tables with the join you are using.
For more help please share some data.

Comment: Please don't YELL.